# Add icon and custom tooltip - y-axis - chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am building a chart using chart.js. I want to add a fontawesome icon in the label of y-axis.

I tried to add - `labelString: 'Range<i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>'`, but it doesn't seem to work. On hover of this icon, I want to also add a tooltip.

How can I add this icon?

Here is the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["Jan", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "Feb"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "data",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 0, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};

function adddata(){
    myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[7] = 60;
  myLineChart.data.labels[7] = "Newly Added";
  myLineChart.update();
}

var option = {
    showLines: true,
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  title: {
    display: false,
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [ {
        scaleLabel: {
        display: true, labelString: 'Range'
      },
      gridLines: {
        drawTicks: false, display: true
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [ {
        scaleLabel: {
        display: true, labelString: 'Last 30 days'
      },
      ticks: {
        min: 0, max: 15, stepSize: 5
      }
    }]
  }

};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
    data:data,
  options:option
});
```

Here is my chart: https://jsfiddle.net/9mg8c6zL/1/